# What is use of XML in messaging protocols

Tags: xml, protocols, messaging

I am not able to understand what is the use of XML in messaging protocols. One of my friend told me find out. Can anybody give an idea with example?

Comment: why there is a negetive vote for this question?

Comment: Not my downvote, but the question does not fit the standards for SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for details.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular protocol that relies on XML is [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) based web services. 
Nowadays SOAP is being largely replaced by [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) based web services and XML formatted message payloads replaced by data formatted using [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

In my opinion this change is fuelled by a desire to simplify a suite of standards that became far too complex. While I miss features like message validation (possible using XML Schemas) one has to admit that JSON is far more efficient for encoding and parsing data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The use of XML in a protocol would be:

- Well defined standard
- Lots of support for creating, verifying and parsing XML
- Self documenting and humanly readable (for debugging)
- Not platform dependant so it transfers between any systems